# Is it a good practice to split CSS?

Tags: php, html, css, performance, split

Is it a good idea to have one CSS file per part of a web page? For example, instead of one large file, I can have several files like this: head.css, container.css, main_menu.css, footer.css, form.css and so on. It helps me manage the design easily, but does it have any drawback?

Also which method is better to include all these files? CSS @import or just using PHP? I read that CSS import might slow down the process, but what if I generate the CSS links using PHP? Something like this:

```
<?php
    $css_dir = opendir("$site_root/includes/css/");

    if ($css_dir !== false)
    {
        $timestamp = time();

        while ( ($one_css = readdir($css_dir)) !== false )
        {
            if ((strpos($one_css, "~") === false) && ($one_css !== ".") && ($one_css !== "..") && ($one_css !== "index.php"))
            {
                echo "<link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href=\"$site_root/includes/css/$one_css?rand=$timestamp\" />\n";
            }
        }
    }

    closedir($css_dir);
?>
```

The problem with the PHP method is that it creates a huge head section for the generated HTML page. Is it a bad thing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a good idea. However, it will be really bad if you try to load the whole css files at a same time. Try to load it on each separated html part.

Comment: I would try to combine as much CSS into a single file, or bundle, as possible. Lots of small files meant lots of http requests which is less efficient. To speed up your CSS, look at CSS minification. Once it's downloaded once, it's cashed anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure this the best approach but this is what I generally follow.

Keeping different CSS files will cause the browser to send multiple requests and increase your page load time. Also, if you're using caching, this approach might cause problems.

You should keep individual CSS files in your project, but when you deploy you should merge them into one or more compressed CSS files. To do this you can use a task runner like [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/).

Comment: +1 for knowing of a tool to combine all the files easily, Grunt

Comment: Thanks. I haven't used a minification tool before, but should try one. Merging should be easy, just one command should do it: "cat *.css > one_big_file.css"

Comment: @lonekingc4 This tool is easy and apart from minifying css it does a lot of other things too. And the best thing is you don't have to run commands all the time. You just run it once and it will perfrom tasks on its own. Try it out.

Answer (score 2):

The browser would fetch each of those files, so technically making several request to get each. Potentially this can add a lot of unneeded/unwanted overhead for each file request.

I see you are using php, not too familiar with the tools for that, but I know at least Visual studio allows you to do something called bundles. You can have several separate files that are easy to manage, and when you deploy the site, it bundles it all together into a single file so it's a single fetch. It may also 'minify' it as well, meaning it'll eliminate non-needed white space that makes the file bigger.  What you are using may have something similar, or I'm sure you can find some service that will do this for you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes and No

If you working for development, yes, you need to separate CSS files because you can modify code very easily.

If you are on deploying sites, no, cause it multiple files waste network traffics.

Additionally, you can use [grunt.js](http://gruntjs.com/), [gulp.js](http://gulpjs.com/) and  [guard](https://github.com/guard/guard) to make things easier and elegantly.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that for development purposes it might be easier to split things up. But keep in mind that in the end it also causes confusion. Often you need to use the same classes in several parts of your page and then if you look at your code a month later, you have no idea where you put the class and have to search all the seperate `CSS` files.

That being said, for performance it would be better to have a single, minified `CSS` file. So even if you have the CSS file seperated, I would use a tool or `PHP` to have all the files put together in one file before you publish to your production environment. Then you only need one `link` tag in your header.

Also keep in mind that using a readdir is fine if your site has a limited amount of visitors. If your site would grow it could also have an impact on performance to read it on every single page request for every user.

So in the end: Use separate files if you want, but group them before you publish to production.